# Grunt - nodemon + watch

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, nodemon, grunt-contrib-sass, grunt-concurrent

i'm new to grunt so i'm guessing i'm doing something simple really wrong. I'm using [angular-client-side-auth](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth) for my single page app and i wanted to add grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-contrib-watch into Gruntfile.js. Here's the problem, when i start the server using nodemon, the watch never run. I tried concurrent, but no luck.

Here's my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Load tasks
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

  //require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks
  grunt.initConfig({
      mochaTest: {
          test: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec'
            },
            src: ['server/tests/**/*.js']
          }
      },
      env : {
        options : {
          //Shared Options Hash
        },
        dev : {
            NODE_ENV : 'development'
        },
        test : {
            NODE_ENV : 'test'
        }
    },

    nodemon: {
        dev: {
            script: 'server.js',
        }
    },
     watch: {
        //options: { nospawn: true, livereload: true },
        sass: {
            files: ["client/css/styles.sass"],
            tasks: ['sass'],
        },
        cssmin: {
            files: ["client/css/styles.sass"],
            tasks: ['cssmin'],
        }
    },
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'client/css/styles.css':  'client/css/styles.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        shorthandCompacting: false,
        roundingPrecision: -1
      },
      target: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'client/css',
          src: ['styles.css', '!*.min.css'],
          dest: 'client/css',
          ext: '.min.css'
        }]
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        },
        tasks: ['watch', 'nodemon:dev']
      }
    },

    clean: ["node_modules", "client/components"]

  });

  grunt.registerTask('serverTests', ['env:test', 'mochaTest']);
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'serverTests']);
  grunt.registerTask('dev', ['env:dev', 'concurrent:dev']);
};
```